# JQuery Popup Opacity

Tags: jquery

```
 <html> 
 <head>
   <script src="jqueryv1.10.2.js"></script>
   <script>
     $(document).ready(function()
     {
       $("#wings").click(function(event)
       {
           loadPopupBox();   
           $("body").css("background","lightgray","opacity","0.4","filter","alpha(opacity=40)");
       });

       $("#popupclose").click(function(event)
       {
           unloadPopupBox();    
           $("body").css("background","#FFF");
       });

       function loadPopupBox()
       {
          $("#popupbox").fadeIn("slow");
       }

       function unloadPopupBox()
       {
          $("#popupbox").fadeOut("normal");
       }
       $("#popupbox").hide();
     });
   </script>
   <style>
    #wings { margin-top:100px; margin-left:550px; font:bold 13px sans-serif; background:orange; 
             float:left; padding:6px; }

    #popupbox { position:fixed; _position:absolute; /*hack for IE6*/ background:#FFF; left:472px; 
                top:150px; border:2px solid lightgray; padding:15px; z-index:100px;
                font-size:15px; -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px lightgray; -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 5px lightgray; 
                box-shadow:0px 0px 5px lightgray; }

    #popupclose { border:0px solid lightgray; color:#6FA5E2; font-family:sans-serif; font-weight:bold; 
                  line-height:15px; float:right; cursor:pointer; text-decoration:none; }
   </style>
 </head>

 <body>
   <div id="wings"> Click Me</div>
   <div id="popupbox">
     <!--div style="height:30px;"><a id="popupclose">Close</a></div>-->
     <!--or-->
     <div style="height:30px;"><img id="popupclose" src="close.png" style="float:right;"/></div>      
     <table>
      <tr><td>USERNAME : </td><td><input type="text" size="30%"></td></tr>
      <tr><td>PASSWORD : </td><td><input type="password" size="30%"></td></tr>    
      <tr><td><input type="submit" value="LOGIN"></td></tr>
     </table> 
   </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

I want a opacity for the background of a body: when I open popup, the body background opacity should be light transparent. Can anyone suggest to set the opacity in jquery itself

Comment: if you are doing multiple css like that you need to do it like this: `.css({ "background":"lightgray", "opacity":"0.4","filter":"alpha(opacity=40)" })`

Comment: Thank You Pete, If I add the css like you said, the popup box and the body background is changing with lightcolor, but I need for the body background

Comment: yeah, if you apply opacity to the body, it would cascade and apply it to all the body's children too

Comment: Why don't you try the jQuery UI dialog window? https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try by setting an opacity=0.3 for exaple to the body and then set and then, set to the popup an opacity=1 !important.
This should work

Here you have how to set opacity http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_transparency.asp

Answer (score 0):

Simplest thing you could do is create a div that will hold the background and change its opacity:

```
<div id="backgrounddiv"></div>
```

Then just style it so it covers the whole page's background. Here's an example taken from an answer to another question here:

```
#backgrounddiv {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: lightgray;
}
```

Finally, when you open the popup, just set the opacity of #backgrounddiv using JQuery like Pete said in his comment:

```
$("#backgrounddiv").css({ "background":"lightgray", "opacity":"0.4","filter":"alpha(opacity=40)" })
```

Comment: Thank You. I took your suggestion, but the popup isn't opening when I click the button. Could you please explain with my code pasted above

Comment: I edited my answer so it's more suitable for this case. Are you getting any errors on the developer console? If you're calling loadPopupBox() before styling the background div it should work.

Comment: Here's a fiddle working as you wanted http://jsfiddle.net/f78f4/3/ I changed the opacity style to background rgba because otherwise everything was becoming transparent and not just the background.